# Using tee (or other command) to log errors or messages to file but only when variable x=="yes"

Tags: bash, shell, logging, tee

I tried using an if statement but this doesn't work as the tee command has the two brackets, one at the start and one at the end.

I tried something like this, which didn't work either

```
if [[ "$logging" == "yes" ]]; then
    ftpt="2>&1 | tee $ftpLF"
else
    ftpt="" 
fi
} "$ftpt"
```

Error:

```
./ftp.sh: line 149: syntax error near unexpected token `"$ftpt"'
./ftp.sh: line 149: `} "$ftpt"'
```

I use this at the moment but I have no option of turning it on/off, it's just always on

```
{
 ....commands....
} 2>&1 | tee "$ftpLF"
```

Comment: Could you give us a bit more context of what the rest of the command you're trying to `tee` looks like?

Comment: " ....commands...." just has a bunch of if statements and FTP commands (ftp upload script)... } 2>&1 | tee /home/user/ftplog.txt there isn't really anything else to give..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option, if you can consistently quote things, is to use `eval` to force Bash to evaluate the added portions of the command:

```
eval '{
  command1 "foo bar" baz
  command2
} "$ftpt"'
```

Another option would be to use an actual named function:

```
ftpcommands() {
  command1 "foo bar" baz
  command2
}

if [[ "$logging" == "yes" ]]; then
    ftpcommands 2>&1 | tee "$ftpLF"
else
    ftpcommands
fi
```

The latter is probably the preferred option, since you don't have to worry about weird quoting issues or other such.